# cannot run upgrade dependancies

Tags: grub2, upgrade, dependencies

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.0.12-00858-gb98721ea4575 aarch64)

after trying upgrade I get this

```
$ sudo apt upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 grub-efi-arm64-signed : Depends: grub-efi-arm64 (= 2.06-2ubuntu10) but 2.06-2ubuntu14 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I tried various suggestions from other posts but success

any ideas

---

Yes I did run `apt update`

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://deb.libre.computer/repo linux InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Fetched 336 kB in 3s (96.9 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
98 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-efi-arm64-signed : Depends: grub-efi-arm64 (= 2.06-2ubuntu10) but 2.06-2ubuntu14 is to be installed

E: Broken packages
```

Output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` :

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold

| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend

|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad) ||/ Name Version Architecture Description +++-========================================-=======================================-============-================================================================================
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` , to update the package list before upgrade ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Update your question with the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'`

Comment: Well, nothing there. Let's see if we find something with `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^[^i]'` . And please delete the answer and update in your question.